# Check one string with dictionary-keys python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have one string (ope_sys) and I would like to guess what string I have using keys (for now these keys are just example) from one dictionary:

```
ope_sys = linux-2.6.32-312-ec2-x86_64-with-debian-6.0.8

def check_os_family(ope_sys):

    inventory_family = {
    "macos": ["macos"],
    "linux": ["linux", "with"],
    "windows": ["windows"]
    }

    for key in inventory_family:
        for i in inventory_family[key]:
            if re.search(i, ope_sys)
                    name = key
    return name
```

The problem I dont know how exactly finish last if after loop over the lists in the dictionary, is there any way to say:

if all ifs are true name = key

Also is there any other way to do that, im open to change all my code.
Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting ope_sys from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are a good approach as long as your matching rules are straightforward.

Note that in your code you could get an error when returning *name*, as it may not have been defined if none of the keywords match.

```py
import re

def check_system(ope_sys):
    system_keywords = {
        "macos": ["macos"],
        "linux": ["linux", "with"],
        "windows": ["windows"],
    }
    for system, keywords in system_keywords.items():
        if all(re.search(kw, ope_sys) for kw in keywords):
            return system
    return None

check_system("linux-2.6.32-312-ec2-x86_64-with-debian-6.0.8")
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pattern-matching, just use what Python gives you: `platform.system()` will return something like "Windows", "Linux", "Darwin" (for Mac OS), etc.

Comment: Actually I getting ope_sys from platform.platform(), but in the future im going to need more details, like debian 6.0, or windonws xp... so just need to add more keys to my dictionary

Comment: Right, so use `platform.release()` to figure out the version.  No need for pattern matching still.

Comment: I tried but with release() only have: 2.6.32-312-ec2

Answer (score 1):

```
for key, value in inventory_family.iteritems():
    if all(v in ope_sys for v in value):
        return key
```